# NodeJs Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment Pubsub

Tags: node.js, linux, publish, google-cloud-pubsub

We are implementing the PubSub Using Client Libraries on for publish data using **Linux and NodeJs**. Also followed all steps of  [Quickstart: Using Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#pubsub-client-libraries-nodejs) .

But we are getting the below error while publish the data

> Received error while publishing: Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment.
> To learn more about authentication and Google APIs, visit:
> https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Thanks for your help in advance !!

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the "Before you begin" section to set up the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to point to a service account file? https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#before-you-begin

Answer (score 2):

If you run into this error, please try following the steps in the "Before you begin" section [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#before-you-begin). One of the steps listed there will set up environment variables indicating the active project id.